# Multiple Resolves And Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I'm using UI-Router in my angular app. I'm also running multiple staged resolves. Let me explain. I want the first resolve to take place, once the promise is returned I then want to activate the second resolve. Here is my solution so far.

```
.state('tab.profile', {
url: '/profile',
reload: true,
cache: false,
views: {
  'tab-profile': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs/profile.html',
    controller: 'ProfileController as profile',
    resolve: {
      signedInUser: function (UserRecord) {
        return UserRecord.retrieve( )
      },
      currentUser: function (signedInUser, User) {
        //signedInUser is returned as null 

        if (signedInUser) {
          return User.show({id: signedInUser.user_id}).$promise;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
})
```

Here is my `UserRecord.retrieve` method.

```
function retrieve() {
var q = $q.defer();

var query = 'SELECT user_credentials, user_id FROM Users;';

$ionicPlatform.ready(function (){
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
      console.log("found user");

      console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
      q.resolve(res.rows[0]);
    } else {
      console.log("no rows found");
      q.resolve(false);

    }
  }, function (err) {
    q.reject(err);
  });
});

return q.promise;
}
```

The problem is that the first resolve coming in is returned as null. I'm not entirely sure what's wrong or what step I'm missing.

Comment: So where does it throw up? When it tries to access ``res.rows`` while res is actually ``null``?

Comment: No, just below `currentUser: function (signedInUser, User) {` inside the function. I made a comment out about it in the code.

Comment: If the only circumstance when the problem comes up is Ionic iOS emulator then IMO the deal is likely unrelated to AngularJS and ui-router’s resolves.